# Localization not working on initial load of the App

Tags: ios, localization

Here's a tricky one.  My App is in English and I also localized it for French.  When I install it on a French device it first loads in English but when I close my App and open it then it loads in French.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes language don't come in expected code like **en** may come **en-US** to avoid this add key to both of your localization files like this

put this in **en** localization file

```
 "appLang"="en";
```

and this in **fr** localization file

```
 "appLang"="fr";
```

when app launches check language like this

```
let ll = NSLocalizedString("appLang", comment: "")

// instance is a shared object has a property to check language property in all parts of the app 

    if(ll == "en")
    {
        instance.isEn= true

         UserDefaults.standard.set([ll], forKey: "AppleLanguages")


    }
    else
    {
        instance.isEn= false

        UserDefaults.standard.set([ll], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    }
```

Also , you may force bundle like that

```
  NSString *lang = (NSString *)[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Next find the bundle for this language:

```
NSBundle *myLangBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj"]];
```

If bundle is found then use it in `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`:

```
_label.text = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"LabelText",nil,myLangBundle,nil);
```

Otherwise find and use default bundle.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work.  The user needs to relaunch the App for the changes to take effect

Comment: check default language

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by check default language ?  My Base language is English and the default language of the device is French.  Initial launch is in English and when i close/re-open it launch in the correct French language.

Comment: do you play with AppleLanguages key during the first launch of app ??

Comment: No, i didn't.  What's funny is that the Push notification request is displaying in French in the initial launch.  But localization is not launching on the initial launch

Comment: yes of course, up to recently it was working fine.  I guess i'll just delete everything and start over

Comment: it may be a problem in files copy content out and delete them from en.proj and fr.proj and re localize again